# JHipster Liquibase multiple Databases

Tags: database, hibernate, jhipster, liquibase

My application needs to connect two to SQL Server Database.
I try to configure them from the Pom.xml file .I try two plugin, I try two configurations of database in the same plugin, this doesn’t work.
I create another DatabaseConfiguration.java with the declaration of another DataSource. But all my services are using the same Entity Manager in Hibernate, and connect to only one database 
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

How can I create another Entity Manager, and associate it to the SpringLiquibase liquibase?
With an annotation @EnableJpaRepositories or directly in code

Comment: This is well explained in Spring Boot doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

Comment: Then for the Liquibase part, you're on your own.

Comment: @Christelle Constancias did you solve the issue? I encounter the same issue. I have 2 entityManager and 2 liquibase beans. Only one liquibase bean (the one named 'liquibase') invoked by spring.